# Autenticação Basica Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

Estou começando agora com NodeJS (vim do PHP), e estou criando uma API para um app meu, gostaria de saber, como faço para fazer as consultas baseado em Auth Basic, eu nao sei muito bem como isso funciona (ja desenvolvi um app para um cliente, que sempre precisava enviar no header `Basic VGVzdDoxMjM=`, nao sei ao certo se era para todas as consultas, ou apenas para o login, mas tambem gostaria de restringir a consulta a minha API. Se nao, so basta a pessoa ter a url da minha API para conseguir executar uma `query`.

Estou usando Mysql para o banco, segue o exemplo de uma consultado.

```
   router.get("/menu", function(req, res){
        let query = "SELECT * FROM ??";
        let table = ["menu"];
        query = mysql.format(query, table);
        connection.query(query, function(err, rows){
            if(err){
                res.json({"Error": true, "Message": "Erro ao executar query do Mysql"});
            }else{
                res.json({"Error": false, "Message": "Sucesso", "Cardapio": rows});
            }
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você quiser que essa autenticação ocorra antes de qualquer consulta, você deve criar uma rota que seja compatível (através de expressão regular, por exemplo) com a uri da requisição e colocá-la no começo do seu arquivo de rotas.
Após isso, você executa sua autenticação e chama `next()` para que a requisição siga seu ciclo de vida normal. Ou passa um erro como parâmetro dentro dessa função para que ela seja tratada pelos middlewares de erros.

```
router.use('*', function(req, res, next) {
    var authKey = req.headers['Authorization'];

    // Executa sua validação
    ...

    // Se tudo ok, segue para a sua rota normalmente
    next();

    // Senão, você pode criar um erro e passar
    // como parâmetro para ser devidamente tratado
    var err = new Error('Not Authorized');
    err.status = 401;
    next(err);
});

router.get("/menu", function(req, res){
    let query = "SELECT * FROM ??";
    let table = ["menu"];
    query = mysql.format(query, table);
    connection.query(query, function(err, rows){
        if(err){
            res.json({"Error": true, "Message": "Erro ao executar query do Mysql"});
        }else{
            res.json({"Error": false, "Message": "Sucesso", "Cardapio": rows});
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Legal, entendi, mas como funcionaria para usar Basic? tipo, eu posso apenas passar via headers e etc? nao preciso de nada mais?

Comment: Sim, se for Basic é só isso mesmo. Tem o padrão aqui, caso você queira dar uma olhada (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7617)